Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. Windows 11
A year ago I made a 30GB partition on drive C to install Linux, but I decided to uninstall it months later due to lack of space. I had it with Windows 11.I formatted the partition and added the 30GB back to the space where I had Windows 11.
On Saturday I was using my laptop and it turned off, when I tried to turn it on it didn't turn on and when it finally did, a message appeared that I don't remember very well what it said, I hit continue and the screen was black. It said "GNU GRUB version 2.06 Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported", I typed the exit command, but the laptop just reboots and the same thing appears again.
I tried to put Windows Boot Manager as the first boot option, but it's not there, only Ubuntu and UEFI Hard Drive are found. With the help of a USB where I downloaded Windows 11, I tried to repair the computer by writing bootrec /fixmbr, /fixboot, /scanos and /rebuildbcd in the command line, in /rebuildbcd I got the message "The requested system device cannot be identified because there are multiple non-distinguishable devices that potentially match the identification criteria."
Then I used the commands diskpart and list volume and I realized that the volume labeled DATA is assigned the letter C and the volume labeled OS is assigned the letter D, when before they were the other way around. I changed them again and then assigned the letter M to the ESP and fs FAT32 tag and typed the command bcdboot c:\Windows /s m: /f all. I turned on the laptop again, but the message I mentioned at the beginning continued to appear and Windows still did not appear in the BIOS.
I don't know what is the problem, I contacted Microsoft support, but they told me to contact Ubuntu support team):

The description of what you did is a big vague, but a bit of interpolation suggests that you damaged your Windows partition and failed to repair the damage before shutdown. If you want the hardware to run Windows, then it's a Windows support question. If you want the hardware to run Ubuntu, then it's an Ubuntu support question. But the question is unclear about your desired end state. Please edit your question to specify Ubuntu, or delete the question if Windows.

use HBCD_PE iso file, make bootable USB flash drive with this iso file. when you boot and reach the normal Windows desktop, use easybcd to install windows bootloader and edit windows boot menu, you can use bootice to correct the partition identification after assign a letter to the drive. see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1521351/1698042

Since you have deleted Ubuntu, this is not really an Ubuntu relevant question, Ubuntu uses the Grub boot-loader which mainly resides in /boot on the Ubuntu partition. You deleted it, so now you don't have a working boot-loader. Boot from a Windwows media and repair the system from there.
